# Accuracy of maths papers wrote in the 1950's

Tags: math-history

I am writing a code that will calculate the solid angle subtended by an off axis disk. I am using the table of answers in [this paper](http://www.umich.edu/~ners312/Course%20Library/SolidAngleOfADiskOffAxis.pdf) on page 257 to check if my code is giving correct answers.

The table says that for a disk with radius 1, a source with distance 0.8 from the disk center and height 1 above the disk center will subtend an angle of 1.3488367 steradians. It also has a reference to [a book](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Tables_of_solid_angles_and_activations.html?id=NmcHgzt-XsAC&redir_esc=y) (which possibly used a different method of calculating the angles) which says the solid angle is 1.34883 steradians.

My code gives the answer 1.348829928531692 steradians. When rounded to the same number of sig figs as the paper this is 1.3488299.

This agrees with the book, but not the paper. The error is only small but it is enough to cause problems for the application I am using.

There are two possible reasons for this error:

1) My code is wrong. I could have a mistake somewhere, it could be a result of rounding done during the calculations, it could be the fact that I use a numerical method to calculate the elliptic integrals used in calculating the solid angle etc.

2) The paper is wrong. I doubt this a little bit as this is a published paper, but I have checked my code meticulously and I can't find any errors.

So my question is this, where papers written around 1959 prone to errors in accuracy due to less powerful/less access to computers? I am hoping that my code gives the more accurate answer, as if it is not I could face problems later on.

Thanks!

*note: In my code I have used the same method as the method discussed in the paper. This method provides an exact solution in terms of elliptic integrals.*

Comment: It might just be a rounding issue by the looks of it

Comment: Perhaps they hit an early version of FDIV :-). Also, global warming may have affected the value of $\pi$.

Comment: If you had to guess, would you say its a rounding issue in my code, or a rounding issue in the paper? I am using matlab, which works with numbers with double precision (16 digits). When F.Paxton wrote this paper he may have done the calculations manually. If so I doubt he used 16 significant figures in his calculations, so my code would give the more accurate answer. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Comment: I would say the possibility of a computational error in the 5th/6th place is significant.

Comment: Are you matching the other numbers in the table?

Comment: Do you have error bounds on the numerical method you use to calculate the elliptic integrals?

Comment: Will Orrick, the ones I have checked have a similar margin of error; e.g 0.8441578 in the paper is 0.844151554844856 in my code, and 0.6370508 is 0.637048890606203 in my code. copper.hat, can you please explain what you mean by "I would say the possibility of a computational error in the 5th/6th place is significant."? Sorry it just confused me a bit. Also the global warming pi joke made me laugh :)

Comment: Gerry Myerson, ellipke(M,tol) computes the complete elliptic integral to accuracy tol. I have tried decreasing the tolerance to tiny values, but it seams to make no difference, so I have just ignored that argument and am using whatever the default tolerance is.

Comment: For what it's worth, the expression they give in terms of complete elliptic integrals of the first and third kinds appears to boil down, for these parameters, to
$$2\pi-5\sqrt{\frac{2}{53}}K(k)-\frac{5}{9}\sqrt{\frac{2}{53}}\Pi(\alpha^2,k)$$
with $k^2=40/53$ and $\alpha^2=80/81.$  *Mathematica* gives the value 1.34882988990910230485937573622 if you ask for 30 place precision.

Comment: Being probably a dynisaur here and having started with computers in 1960, I am not sure that at that time we had access to double precision. This could explain these differences.

Comment: @Blue7: Well, I don't know what they used for computations, but I think 8 decimal digits precision in the late 1950's would be typical/good. You are looking at errors in the 6th place which could easily arise without higher precision intermediate results, guard digits, etc. Appreciation for the subtleties of numerical floating point computations took some time.

Comment: If I had to bet, I'd bet that your answer is the correct one. In the 1960's, six or seven significant digits was considered pretty good. Can't you concoct an example where you can easily get the correct answer by hand calculation?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm going to assume that mine is the more accurate answer. @bubba, i can't get the answer by hand as I need matlab to compute the elliptic integrals numerically. I guess I could use simpsons rule or a similar method but I presume matlab will be more accurate.

Comment: I was assuming that there are some simple cases that don't require elliptical integrals. When the offset of the disk center is zero, for example.